# spark Dataframe execute UPDATE statement

Tags: apache-spark, sql-update, sql-insert, apache-spark-sql

Hy guys,

I need to perform jdbc operation using Apache Spark DataFrame.
Basically I have an historical jdbc table called Measures where I have to do two operations:

**1. Set endTime  validity  attribute of the old measure record to the current time**

**2. Insert a new measure record setting endTime to 9999-12-31**

Can someone tell me how to perform (if we can) update statement for the first operation and insert for the second operation?

I tried to use this statement for the first operation:

```
val dfWriter = df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
dfWriter.jdbc("jdbc:postgresql:postgres", tableName, prop)
```

But it doesn't work because there is a duplicate key violation. If we can do update, how we can do delete statement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think its supported out of the box yet by Spark. What you can do it iterate over the dataframe/RDD using the foreachRDD() loop and manually update/delete the table using JDBC api.

here is link to a similar question : 
[Spark Dataframes UPSERT to Postgres Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643200/spark-dataframes-upsert-to-postgres-table)

Comment: Incredible that this lack has not yet been fixed after all this time! https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19335