# How to create a encoder for type Iterator[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark 2.4.4 in databricks notebook. 
I have a data in dataframe which I want to use to update records in Postgre table .
I am following the approach given in this post [Spark Dataframes UPSERT to Postgres Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643200/spark-dataframes-upsert-to-postgres-table/34643784#34643784)

Here is my code

```
import spark.implicits._ 

val update_query = s"""UPDATE scored_fact.f_learner_assessment_item_response_classifications_test SET is_deleted = ? where f.learner_assigned_item_classification_attempt_sk = ?::uuid AND f.root_org_partition= ?::int"""


changedSectionLearnerDF.coalesce(8).mapPartitions((d) => Iterator(d)).foreach { batch =>
  val dbc: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl)
  val stmt: PreparedStatement = dbc.prepareStatement(update_query)

  batch.grouped(100).foreach { session =>
    session.foreach { row =>
      stmt.setBoolean( 0, row.getAs[Boolean]("is_deleted") )
     stmt.setString( 1, row.getAs[String]("learner_assigned_item_classification_attempt_sk"))
     stmt.setString( 2, row.getAs[String]("root_org_partition"))
     stmt.addBatch()
    }
    stmt.executeBatch()
  }
  dbc.close()
}
```

I am getting below error

```
Unable to find encoder for type Iterator[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]. An implicit Encoder[Iterator[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]] is needed to store Iterator[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] instances in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.changedSectionLearnerDF.coalesce(8).mapPartitions((d) => Iterator(d)).foreach { batch =>
```

I am sure I am missing something. How can I resolve this error by creating an encoder

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `mapPartitions` is

```
def mapPartitions[U](func: (Iterator[T]) ⇒ Iterator[U])(implicit arg0: Encoder[U]): Dataset[U]
```

So `d` in `d => Iterator(d)` is an `Iterator[Row]` and the function returns a `Dataset[Iterator[Row]]` which can't reasonably exist.

I think the `mapPartitions` call is simply wrong and `.mapPartitions((d) => Iterator(d)).foreach` should be replaced by `foreachPartition` (as @shridharama's comment to the linked answer says).