# Azure databricks - Do we have postgres connector for spark

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Azure databricks - Do we have postgres connector for spark
Also, how to upsert/update record in postgres using spark databricks.
I am using Spark 3.1.1
When trying to write using mode=overwrite, it truncates the table but recird is not getting inserted
I am new to this. Please help.

Comment: It is not supported. you can refer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643200/spark-dataframes-upsert-to-postgres-table.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a separate connector for PostgreSQL - it works via standard [JDBC connector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html), and PostgreSQL JDBC driver should be included into databricks runtime - check [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/runtime/releases) for your specific runtime. So you just need to form a correct JDBC URL as described in [documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html) (Spark documentation also has [examples](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) of URL for PostgreSQL).

Something like this:

```py
df.write \
  .format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver") \
  .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename") \
  .option("user", "username") \
  .option("password", "password") \
  .save()
```

Regarding the UPSERT, it's not so simple, not only for PostgreSQL, but also for other databases:

- either you do the full join, and select entries not existing only in your dataset, and the rest is taking from the database, and then overwrite - but this is very expensive because you're reading a full database, and writing it back
- or you're doing left join with database (you need to read it again) going down to RDD with `.foreachPartition/.foreach`,  and forming a series of INSERT/UPDATE operations depending on if data exist in database, or not - it's doable, but you need more experience.
- Specifically for PosgtreSQL you can convert this (`foreach`) into `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` so you won't need to read full database (see [their wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/UPSERT) for more information about this operation)

Another approach - write your data into temporary table, and then via JDBC issue the [MERGE command](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/23520/sql-merge.html) to incorporate your changes into the table. This is more "lightweight" method from my point of view.